# When can one have light in the room during marital relations?

Tags: halacha, sexuality, lighting

According to tradition, relations should take place at night and in the dark. The Talmud forbids relations during the day or by the light of a lamp (Niddah 17).

Are there circumstances where having light in the room and thereby seeing one's wife is permitted during marital relations?

for example, for couples with marital problems where this would enhance their intimacy.

Please cite sources.

Comment: similar http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/45392/759

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/22097/759

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5550/759

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/57184/759

Answer (score 3):

See the Rambam in [הלכות איסורי ביאה Ch 21](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/5121.htm):10 that it's forbidden.

However, it would seem, that having the lights on before and after the act would be allowed - along with everything else in 21:9.

> **ט** אשתו של אדם, מותרת היא לו; לפיכך **כל מה שאדם רוצה לעשות באשתו, עושה**--בועל בכל עת שירצה, ומנשק בכל אבר שירצה, ובא עליה בין כדרכה, בין שלא כדרכה, בין דרך אברים.  ואף על פי כן, מידת חסידות שלא יקל אדם את ראשו לכך, ושיקדש עצמו בשעת תשמיש, כמו שביארנו בהלכות דעות; ולא יסור מדרך העולם ומנהגו, שאין דבר זה אלא כדי לפרות ולרבות.
>    ‏
>
> **י** אסור לאדם לשמש מיטתו, לאור הנר; הרי שהייתה ליל שבת, ולא היה לו בית אחר, והיה הנר דולק--הרי זה לא ישמש כלל.  וכן אסור לישראלי לשמש מיטתו ביום, שעזות פנים היא.  ואם היה תלמיד חכמים, שאינו בא להימשך בכך--הרי זה מאפיל בטליתו, ומשמש; ואין נזקקין לדבר זה, אלא מפני צורך גדול.  ודרך קדושה, לשמש באמצע הלילה. ‏

Answer (score 3):

The relevant discussion is in [S.A. O.C. 240](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x1065). The Mechaber seems to forbid without exception (the Taz brings the Arizal that says the same thing). The Ramo allows an indirect light (as in through a sheet or reflected off of a wall), however the Taz and the Shach there both say that in such a circumstance it is limited to the same exception as by day - one has to be covered (Mehapech BeTaliso) so as to not be able to see.

So the upshot is that maybe according to the Ramo - and this is quite controversial - some limited indirect light may be permissible.

Comment: There is no Shakh to OC...